# Correct procedure for updating page data without page reload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

Morning all, so im writing a cms for learning but keep coming across the same issue.

When e.g., updating a blog post i want the data to be changed without the page reloading. This way the user can see it happen and doesnt have to scroll back to the post. Same goes with everything, deleting, moving, editing titles etc.

Currently i use .load(). But its causing havoc with my scripts.

I use ckEditor, and if i reload a div using .load, the ckEditor isnt there so im guessing the script isnt working / loaded. All of my updates are made with an ajax call and if do a .load then try to do another update action (without refreshing the page) it goes to the php page and ignores the javascript ajax call and validation etc.

Heres an example:

```
if (check) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "process/deletepost.php",
                data: $targetForm.serialize(),
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {

                    if (response.deleteSuccess)
                    $targetForm.find('.editor').toggle(),
                    <!-- Check for .buildtext id etc to prevent it showing any other posts when updating it -->
                    $("#container").load(response.pageurl + "#container"),
                    $targetForm.find('.edity').toggle(),
                    $targetForm.find('.saveupdatebutton').toggle(),
                    $targetForm.find('.deleteupdatebutton').toggle();
                    else
                    $ckEditor.after('<div class="error">Something went wrong!</div>');

                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    }
```

the #container holds all of the blog posts so the aim was to just reload them all.

Any help on where im going wrong / what i SHOULD be doing to load data live as to say.

Thanks, Craig.

Answer (score 1):

You can JQuery Template instead of load function .Just Create a Template of your Blog,bring the data using Ajax call and Append the Template along with data.

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "process/Update.php",
     data: $targetForm.serialize(),
     dataType: "json",
     success: function (response) {
          $("#template_Name").tmpl(response.Data).prependTo($("#somediv"));
             //do Something
          }
     });
```

Write Template as

```
<script id="template_Name" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
     <div id="${blogid}">
        ${BlogData}
     </div>   
</script>
```